# trying to display JSON with 422 error Rails React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have an app with Rails as a backend and React as a frontend. I am trying to handle [Stripe errors](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors) on server side and render any error by updating my state in the client.

here the code in my controller method:

```
def create
  # here some code to handle payment...
   rescue Stripe::CardError => e
     render json: e.json_body[:error][:message], status: 422
  end
```

and my react function that handles the response:

```
  axios.post("/orders"})
  .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        hasOrdered: true,
        orderSuccess: true,
        loading: false
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      error: err
    });
  });
```

the `console.log(err)` output is simply: `Error: Request failed with status code 422` whereas the response I get through the network is:

[image: network tab outbut in the browser]

And what I want is the update the state with "Your card has insufficient funds."

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK got the solution: I have to access `err.response.data` :

```
 .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.data);
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      error: err.response.data
    });
```